# App Store Buttons

Tags: iphone, app-store, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

How does the App Store create the "Top Paid" "Top Free" and "Release Date" buttons?

They look like UIBarButtonItems in a UIToolbar but with a catch. The buttons merge together into one longer button. If it is a UIToolbar, I'm not sure how they connect the buttons so that they appear together like a tab bar ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't have the iPhone right here, but I think what you want is the `UISegmentedControl`. Does it look like this?

[image: UISegmentedControl]
<sub>(source: [episode-2.com](http://blog.episode-2.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/uisegmentedcontrol-3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: That's right. I'd seen the 'default' one but missed the segmentedControlStyle property for the smaller, toolbar version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think they must be using a [UISegmentedControl](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/09/here-is-how-you-use-the-segmented-control-uisegmentedcontrol/)